# Printing variable value inside asp:Checkbox on aspx vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

This is the example of what we want to do: we want the ID and Text properties to be dynamic according to the list of elements.

```
<table style="width:100%">
<%
    For Each elem In list
        %>
            <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="CheckValidador" ID="elem.ID" Text="elem.Name" />
        <%
    Next
%>
</table>
```

Comment: Use a Repeater Control

Comment: Pro tip : Sentences like *Please help, I am going crazy.* are not necessary and are not recommended to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a CheckBoxList control.

The checkBoxlist, gridview, listview, repeater (and a few more) ALL support data binding. And thus you can drive the number of check boxes based on the data you send/provide/have to that control.

So, say we have this data in our table:

[image]

So, our markup would be this:

```
        <h2>Pick your favorte fruit</h2>
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" 
            DataValueField="ID" DataTextField="Food"
            RepeatDirection="Horizontal" >
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

And our code is thus:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadData
    End If
End Sub

Sub LoadData()
    Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("SELECT ID, Food from Food ORDER BY Food",
                    New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST3))

        cmdSQL.Connection.Open()
        CheckBoxList1.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader
        CheckBoxList1.DataBind()

    End Using
End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

And if you only want ONE allowed choice, then use a RadioButtion list - it will work identical to above.

It often depends on where you data is coming from. You can use a list or other sources for the above. And you can use a loop - but in most cases you don't need to.